# Trie with custom insert and delete functions

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, trie

I need to create four custom function for a Trie data structure without changing its O(n) complexity:

- makeDir("pathToDir")
- make("pathToFile")
- delete("pathToDir")
- forceDelete("pathToDirOrFile")

makeDir("pathToDir"): adds path to the trie only if it is a valid path

make("pathToFile"): adds path to the trie only if it is a valid path (a file node can't call makeDir() )

delete("pathToDir"): deletes the path from trie only if it has no child dirs

forceDelete("pathToDirOrFile"): deletes path and its child dirs

For example a list of commands would be:

```
makeDir("\dir");
makeDir("\dir\foo")
makeDir("\dir\foo\lol\ok"); /* incorrect path */
make("\dir\file");
makeDir("\dir\file\abc"); /* file can't have sub dirs */
delete("\dir"); /* has childs, incorrect */
delete("\dir\file");
forceDelete("\dir");
```

Does anybody have any idea on how to recognize that the node indicates the path of a files? What is the best way to implement these functions?

Comment: What does a "valid path" means exactly?

Comment: You can understand it in the example, as you can see at the third row the *lol* folder doesn't exist therefore that is an invalid path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Validating and splitting the path

It's OS specific, so just pick any library that works with paths for your target system.

### The trie

Once you can split a path into pieces, you can build a trie. Keep strings in its edges. For instance, if you have a `foo/bar` path, there'll be 3 nodes and two edges: the first one (1->2) is marked with `foo` and the second one (2->3) is marked with `bar`.

You can store a flag in each node to indicate if it's a regular file or a directory.

To check if a directory is empty, just make sure it's node has no children.

To check if a directory/file can be created, take its base dir (all parts of the path except the last one), check that it exists by traversing your trie from the root and that its node is a directory, not a regular file.

### Efficient traversal

You can store edges in hash table that maps a string to a node.

Comment: I thought that trie had O(n) complexity only if it had a single char as key, will this method have the same time-complexity as the common trie one?
Also, one more question, you say there will be 3 nodes and two edges, what is the third node? The root?

Comment: @Yes, the root is also a node. It's `O(n)`, where `n` is the length of the path.

Comment: How would you find a node just by its name? I mean without telling the function the whole path to it.

Comment: @Matt95 Why would you need to find a node without traversing the full path?

Comment: I am required to do that too, just wondering what was the fastest way

Comment: @Matt95 What's do you mean by name? Isn't it full path?

Comment: Let's say I've already created the path `/foo/bar/file/dex/march/april` and I want to create a function `node* search(char* nodeName)` that returns the pointer to that node.
So if I call `node* ptr = search("march")` *ptr* will be a pointer to *march* folder

Comment: @Matt95 You can't do that in general case. There can be a lot of files with the same name (in different directories).

Comment: @Matt95 You can store a hash map from a node name to a set of pointers if you can choose an arbitrary one when there're several options.

Comment: Not really into hash maps and hash functions, is that the only reasonable way to do it?

Comment: Also, forgot to say that filenames are not repeated in this case

Comment: @Matt95 It depends on the definition of reasonable, but the good thing is that most modern languages provide a hash table and a hash function for standard types so you don't need to build it on your own.

Comment: Unfortunately I am allowed to use only C, lucky me. And its libc library.
The precise complexity required is O(d + f^2) where d is the number of items in the tree (so the number of nodes) and f is the number of nodes found in a research.

Comment: I've created the tree the way you said but the function make() and makeDir() don't have a O(n) complexity cause give the path the function will head to the children of the root, it then has to compare every child of the root till it finds the correct one, then goes to that child's child and compare again and so on. Am I wrong?